# "no step-definition method match found for" when attempting to put part of the response in a variable (using 'def')

Tags: karate

I'm trying to put part of my PUT response body in a variable, cause I will be using this information later in the same test, but for some reason I cannot do that:
[image]

As you can see, I can print that part of the response (the ID), so I guess there's nothing wrong with the syntax/address I'm using to reach it in the print. When attempting to put the same information in a variable, it is not possible.

It is probably something simple, and I'm new to KarateDSL, so I hope you guys can help me figure out this one. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate has a convention for variable names, and hyphens are not allowed. Underscores are. So you can do this:

```
* def equipment1 = response['foo'][0].bar
```

Or:

```
* def equipment_1 = response['foo'][0].bar
```